# How to export all sheets in a Spreadsheet as CSV files using the Drive API with a Service Account in Python?

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I've built a successful service connection to the Drive API already, and I’m creating export URLs to download each sheet in a Spreadsheet as a CSV file by sending requests with Google’s AuthorizedSession class. For some reason, only a portion of the CSV files come back correct, with the others containing broken HTML. When I send a single request, the sheet always comes back correct, but when I loop through the sheets and start sending requests things start to break. I've identified there's a problem with how I'm passing the credentials this way, but I'm not sure if I'm using AuthorizedSession correctly. Can anyone help me figure this one out?

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
import re
import shutil
import urllib.parse


CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = "client_secret.json"
API_NAME = "sheets"
API_VERSION = "v4"
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"]
SPREADSHEET_ID = "Spreadsheet ID goes here"
print(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES, sep="-")

cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scopes=SCOPES
)

try:
    service = build(API_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
    print(API_NAME, "service created successfully")
    result = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID).execute()
    export_url = re.sub("\/edit$", "/export", result["spreadsheetUrl"])
    authed_session = AuthorizedSession(cred)

    for sheet in result["sheets"]:
        sheet_name = sheet["properties"]["title"]
        params = {"format": "csv", "gid": sheet["properties"]["sheetId"]}
        query_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
        url = export_url + "?" + query_params
        response = authed_session.get(url)

        file_path = "./Downloads/" + sheet_name + ".csv"
        with open(file_path, "wb") as csv_file:
            csv_file.write(response.content)
            print("Downloaded sheet: " + sheet_name)
    print("Downloads complete")
except Exception as e:
    print("Unable to connect")
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should get you a sheetsservice

```
"""Hello sheets."""

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


SCOPES = ['"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '<REPLACE_WITH_JSON_FILE>'
VIEW_ID = '<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>'


def initialize_sheet():
  """Initializes an sheetservice object.

  Returns:
    An authorized sheetservice object.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  sheet= build('sheet', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

  return sheet
```

If you use the same sheet service built by this method then you souldnt have any issues looping

Answer (score 1):

I think that your script of `authed_session = AuthorizedSession(cred)` and `response = authed_session.get(url)` are correct. I thought that in your situation, the number of requests might be large in the short time, and this might be due to the reason of your issue. So as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for sheet in result["sheets"]:
    sheet_name = sheet["properties"]["title"]
    params = {"format": "csv", "gid": sheet["properties"]["sheetId"]}
    query_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    url = export_url + "?" + query_params
    response = authed_session.get(url)

    file_path = "./Downloads/" + sheet_name + ".csv"
    with open(file_path, "wb") as csv_file:
        csv_file.write(response.content)
        print("Downloaded sheet: " + sheet_name)
```

#### To:

```
for sheet in result["sheets"]:
    sheet_name = sheet["properties"]["title"]
    params = {"format": "csv", "gid": sheet["properties"]["sheetId"]}
    query_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    url = export_url + "?" + query_params
    response = authed_session.get(url)

    file_path = "./Downloads/" + sheet_name + ".csv"
    with open(file_path, "wb") as csv_file:
        csv_file.write(response.content)
        print("Downloaded sheet: " + sheet_name)

    time.sleep(3)  # <--- Added. Please adjust the value of 3 for your actual situation.
```

- In this case, please use `import time`.